# Something I don't understand about js await

Tags: javascript, async-await

I am using await to complete a css transition before continuing with other code. In [this fiddle][1] the fadeIn and fadeOut async functions include an await that is intended to resolve when the transition ends.

```js
function transTo(el, className) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    el.ontransitionend = () => resolve();
    el.classList.add(className);
  });
}

function transFrom(el, className) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    el.ontransitionend = () => resolve();
    el.classList.remove(className);
  });
}
async function fadeIn(el) {
  el.style.display = "block";
  await transTo(el, "show");
}

async function fadeOut(el) {
  await transFrom(el, "show");
  el.style.display = "none";
}
const basic = document.querySelector(".blockA");
const btnFadeIn = document.querySelector(".btn.fade-in");
const btnFadeOut = document.querySelector(".btn.fade-out");

btnFadeIn.onclick = () => {
  fadeIn(basic);
  console.log("fade in");
}
btnFadeOut.onclick = () => {
  fadeOut(basic);
  console.log("fade out");
}
```

```css
.basic {
  position: absolute;
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 5s ease-in-out;
}

.show {
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn {
  margin-left: 200px;
  background: lightblue;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="blockA"></div>
<button class="btn fade-in">Fade In</button>
<button class="btn fade-out">Fade Out</button>
```

The fadeOut appears to work correctly but the fadeIn does not. Also the console.logs execute immediately though I expected them to be delayed until the transition was over. Clearly I am missing something; can somebody explain why this doesn't work reliably?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `onclick` handlers also need to `await` the functions they call.

Like this:

```
btnFadeIn.onclick = async () => {
  await fadeIn(basic);
  console.log("fade in");
}

btnFadeOut.onclick = async () => {
  await fadeOut(basic);
  console.log("fade out");
}
```